# How to split a dataframe to multiple dataframes bases on column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My dataframe is as below,

```
 _dict = {'t_head': ['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5','H6'], 
            'r_head': ['Revenue', 'Revenue', 'Income', 'Income', 'Cash', 'Expenses'], 
            '3ME__ Q219': [159.9, '', 45.6, '', '', ''], 
            '3ME__ Q218': [112.3, '', 27.2, '', '', ''], 
            '3ME__ Q119': [121.0, '', 23.1, '', '', ''], 
            '3ME__ Q18': [85.7, '', 15.3, '', '', ''], 
            '3ME__ Q418': [160.5, '', 51.1, '', '', ''], 
            '9ME__ Q417': [102.6, '', 24.2, '', '', ''], 
            '9ME__ Q318': [118.8, '', 30.2, '', '', ''], 
            '9ME__ Q317': [79.4, '', 15.3, '', '', ''], 
            '6ME__ Q219': ['', 280.9, '', 68.7, '', ''], 
            '6ME__ Q218': ['', 198.0, '', 42.6, '', ''], 
            'Q219': ['', '', '', '', 1305, 1239], 
            'Q418': ['', '', '', '', 2072, 1117]
            }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(_dict)
print(df)  

  t_head    r_head 3ME__ Q219 3ME__ Q218 3ME__ Q119 3ME__ Q18 3ME__ Q418 9ME__ Q417 9ME__ Q318 9ME__ Q317 6ME__ Q219 6ME__ Q218  Q219  Q418
0     H1   Revenue      159.9      112.3        121      85.7      160.5      102.6      118.8       79.4                                  
1     H2   Revenue                                                                                             280.9        198            
2     H3    Income       45.6       27.2       23.1      15.3       51.1       24.2       30.2       15.3                                  
3     H4    Income                                                                                              68.7       42.6            
4     H5      Cash                                                                                                               1305  2072
5     H6  Expenses                                                                                                               1239  1117
```

I want to split this dataframe into multiple dtaframes base on column heading. Here column headings **can** start with `3ME__`,`6ME__`,`9ME__` (*all/any/none can be present*) or other values. i want to all columns starting with `3ME__` to be in one dataframe,`6ME__` to another...etc. and the all of the rest to be in a fourth dataframe.
What i had tried is as below,

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='3ME__')
if not df1.empty:
    df1 = df1[df1.iloc[:,0].astype(bool)]
df2 = df.filter(regex='6ME__')
if not df2.empty:
    df2 = df2[df2.iloc[:,0].astype(bool)]
df3 = df.filter(regex='9ME__')
if not df3.empty:
    df3 = df3[df3.iloc[:,0].astype(bool)]
```

Here i am able to filter out column names starting with`3ME__`,`6ME__` & `9ME__` to different dataframes, but **not able to get the rest of column headings to one dataframe**.

1.) *How to get the rest of column headings to one dataframe?*
2.) *Is there any simpler method to split into dictionary with a key and dataframes as values?*

Please Help.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly naming the columns you want to store into a new dataframe using loc?

Comment: i cannot rename the columns as the dataframe is the output of a web scraper.

Comment: No I mean `new_df = df[['3ME__ Q219', '3ME__ Q218' .... '3ME__ Q21n']]`

Comment: If the column name varies and you want to just check for a "keyword" like "3ME", store your df column names into a list and do split per entry then store into new lists which of the names returned true or false, then use those lists to refer back to your df using their indexes in `df.colums`

Comment: @Joe, as is is the output of a webscraper, i do not know what will be the dataframe headers. The dtataframe may or maynot contain column headers  starting with `3ME__`,`6ME__'..etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do the below:

```
m=df.set_index(['t_head','r_head']) #set the 2 columns as index
```

Then split columns and group by on axis 1 and make a dict with each group

```
d={f'df_{i}': g for i, g in m.groupby(m.columns.str.split('_').str[0],axis=1)}
```

Then call each key to access this dictionary:

```
print(d['df_3ME'])
```

---

Based on further discussion we do the same operation but with a condition:

```
cond=df.columns.str.contains('__') #check if cols have double _
d={f'df_{i}':g for i, g in 
   df.loc[:,cond].groupby(df.loc[:,cond].columns.str.split('__').str[0],axis=1)}
d.update({'Misc':df.loc[:,~cond]}) #update the dict with all that doesnt meet condition
print(d['df_3ME'])
```

---

```
  3ME__ Q219 3ME__ Q218 3ME__ Q119 3ME__ Q18 3ME__ Q418
0      159.9      112.3        121      85.7      160.5
1                                                      
2       45.6       27.2       23.1      15.3       51.1
3                                                      
4                                                      
5
```

---

```
print(d['Misc'])

  t_head    r_head  Q219  Q418
0     H1   Revenue            
1     H2   Revenue            
2     H3    Income            
3     H4    Income            
4     H5      Cash  1305  2072
5     H6  Expenses  1239  1117
```

Comment: i have tried this method, but it will create seperate dataframes for `others`, ie in this case seperate df for `Q418` and `Q219`. I want all others to be in one dataframe.

Comment: @Shijith set all such columns as index and then try this method. How many such columns do you have?

Comment: here i am not sure what the dataframe will contain, i am expecting a dataframe with `t_head`,`r_head` and some values (dont know what values - can differ)

Comment: @Shijith then based on what do you intend to group them together? as I see, any column can have a `_`

Comment: last two columns doesnt have `'__'`,  i want to split into diffrent dataframes if `len(df.columns.str.split('__')) == 2` on `m.columns.str.split('_').str[0]', for the rest of column headings with `lenth ==1` should all be grouped to one dataframe

Comment: ok please allow some time, I am at work now, I will check this later in the evening @Shijith :)

Comment: Thank you, it will be of great help. For now i have got a workaround, but it has around 20 lines of code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199006/discussion-between-anky-91-and-shijith).

Answer (score 1):

You can retreive the column names of your created dataframes and select by the columns that are not in it:

```
other_columns = [x for x in df.columns if x not in (list(df1.columns) + list(df2.columns) + list(df3.columns))]

other_df = df[other_columns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this also:

```
k = list(df1.columns)+ list(df2.columns)+ list(df3.columns)

df = df.drop(k, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of all the above got me to the what i was looking for,

```
def _split_dataframes(df):
    df = df.set_index(['t_head','r_head'])
    final_dict_key = 0
    final_dict = {}
    names_list = []
    for elems in ['3ME__','6ME__','9ME__','other']:
        if elems != 'other':
            temp_df = df.filter(regex=elems)
            temp_df = temp_df.loc[(temp_df!='').all(axis=1)]
            names_list.extend(list(temp_df.columns))
            if not temp_df.empty:
                temp_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
                final_dict[str(final_dict_key)] = temp_df
                final_dict_key+= 1

        else:
            df.drop(names_list, axis=1,inplace=True)
            df = df.loc[(df!='').all(axis=1)]
            if not df.empty:
                df.reset_index(inplace=True)
                final_dict[str(final_dict_key)] = df
```

this will split the main dataframe and save to a dictionary with an incremental-key as below

```
{
 '0':
     t_head   r_head 3ME__ Q219 3ME__ Q218 3ME__ Q119 3ME__ Q18 3ME__ Q418
   0     H1  Revenue      159.9      112.3        121      85.7      160.5
   1     H3   Income       45.6       27.2       23.1      15.3       51.1, 
 '1': 
     t_head   r_head 6ME__ Q219 6ME__ Q218
   0     H2  Revenue      280.9        198
   1     H4   Income       68.7       42.6, 
 '2':
      t_head   r_head 9ME__ Q417 9ME__ Q318 9ME__ Q317
   0     H1  Revenue      102.6      118.8       79.4
   1     H3   Income       24.2       30.2       15.3, 
 '3':
      t_head    r_head  Q219  Q418
   0     H5      Cash  1305  2072
   1     H6  Expenses  1239  1117
}
```